# Get instance of another element via Xaml Binding (Attached or DependencyProperty)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, binding

I have a use case where I want to get at a reference to an element in Xaml from another element.

For instance, consider this simplistic case. I have a UserControl called A and a UserControl called B, 
and somehow I want to register an attached property where B can get the reference to A.

e.g.

```
<MyCustomControl Name="A"/>
<MyCustomControl Name="B" 
                 AttachedPropClass.TheOtherControl="{Binding ElementName=A}"/>
```

So I would expect B.TheOtherControl to be equal to A. Is this possible in Xaml? Note I am *not* binding to a property of A, but rather I want the whole element.

Any solution using DependencyProperties, or AttachedProperties or Behaviors that lets me do this in Xaml would be great.

**Edit:** I'm attempting to do this in both WPF and Silverlight4. I have tried the above and it doesn't work, a property changed callback on the Attached property never gets hit.

Comment: Well, did you try it? The code you wrote looks fine...

Comment: Yes, I should've said, I've tried this and it doesn't work. I also tried a DependencyProperty on MyCustomControl and bound B.TheOther to A via ElementName. Neither worked. I have a PropertyChanged callback on the dependency property and it never gets hit. So, at least I'm not doing something stupid and the above is syntactically correct? Perhaps there is something else wrong.

Comment: tried `BindsDirectlyToSource`?

Comment: Can you copy your Attached properties here ??

Comment: Thanks @ExitMusic - never knew about that property. So what would an example be in this case? Bear in mind I can implement TheOtherControl as a DependencyProperty on MyCustomControl instead of Attached Prop if that helps.

Comment: To be honest that's not what you are looking for. I recreated your problem. I think you may need to use behaviours like Paul Marques says

Comment: Post. Your. Code.  That XAML means nothing without the attached property code that goes with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Behaviour with a property that you set to the Control name and then search the logical Tree for the control.  I have a similar thing where I want a certain event on one control to move focus to another control.  I do this by specifying the control name to the Behaviour.

```
<TextBox Name="A"/>
<TextBox Name="B">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Behaviours1:ProgressNextOnEnterAction NextTextBoxControlName="A" />
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I actually ended up using an approach similar to this. I created an attached property which accepted a string and passed in the name of the other element, did a VisualTree walk to find it. So can be done with AttachedProps not just behaviors. Thanks for the info! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I figured out what happened.

Declare your dependency property like this:

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty TheOtherControlProperty =
                              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                      "TheOtherControl",
                                      typeof(MyCustomControl),
                                      typeof(AttachedPropClass),// Change this part
                                      null);

    public static MyCustomControlGetTheOtherControl(MyCustomControltarget)
    {
        return (MyCustomControl)target.GetValue(TheOtherControlProperty);
    }
    public static void SetTheOtherControl(MyCustomControltarget, TextBlock value)
    {
        target.SetValue(TheOtherControlProperty, value);
    }
```

I think the issue is that you set the `OwnerType` of the Dependency Property to `MyCustomControl` instead of to `AttachedPropClass`.

I've created an example that works.

Give this a try and let me know if I'm right.

u_u

Comment: Thanks for the example, really appreciate it. let me try this and get back to you :)

Comment: Update, that was pretty much what I had, except the Attached Property was declared in the MyCustomControl (so both types were the same). Unfortunately no matter what I did, I couldn't get this to work. Thanks for the help anycase!

Comment: weird... I'll see if I can recreate that

Comment: So `"{Binding ElementName=A}"` is valid then? Never knew!